# API request returning NULL on HEROKU, but working locally Discord.js Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, discord

I'm working on a Discord BOT using Node.js

I'm trying to get an image using a public API with no key needed, it's working locally but when I deploy it on Heroku, it doesn't work.

I need to know if Heroku is limiting the API requests and I should upgrade my "free" plan or I'm missing something.

Error message when trying to call the API :

`2020-06-02T22:37:20.973482+00:00 app[worker.1]: Mister Secret is online !
2020-06-02T22:37:47.205353+00:00 app[worker.1]: rpstorydiscord just joined the server.
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831240+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Server responded with 403
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831256+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:56:28
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831257+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/node_modules/simple-get/index.js:89:7
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831258+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at PassThrough.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/simple-concat/index.js:7:13)
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831258+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831258+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at PassThrough.emit (events.js:315:20)
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831259+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
2020-06-02T22:37:49.831259+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)`

The API request looks like this :

https://api.habbocity.me/avatar_image.php?user=PSEUDO&headonly=0&direction=3&head_direction=3&size=l

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to show the error message. You didn't do that. Chances are you are running into a CORS error, which is not heroku's problem, but how you're calling the API, but we won't know UNLESS you get us the error messages.

Comment: It's edited ! Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you went to the API directly, you are hit with a captcha check. So I suspect your API call hit the same problem. Guess you'll have to take it up with the API provider on how to bypass that.  https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001992652-Using-Privacy-Pass-with-Cloudflare#:~:text=Overview,experience%20for%20Cloudflare%2Dprotected%20websites.&text=After%20a%20single%20captcha%20page,websites%20to%20prevent%20frequent%20captcha.

Comment: Oh thank you for clarifying that. By the way, how did you know that there's a captcha check ?

Comment: I opened your api.habbocity.me URL directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API call was blocked with a site-wide CAPTCHA from the web host Cloudflare. Any call to that domain is blocked with the CAPTCHA, unless you get a token from their "privacy-pass" extension/plug-in.

It worked on localhost because you already have such a token downloaded.